# Detecting WebAudio sound end

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I'm using a javascript build a radio and I'm trying to give it different functionalities but I need to be able to detect the end of a song to make it work. Is there any way to do this?

I've tried different methods I've found online like .ended and such but I don't think those work without using the html audio tag. So I tried to make an audio tag that uses the same data for the source that my js radio uses and get the file length to stop my sourceNode at the end time and make a new one but but i keep getting null returned as the data so that doesn't work either.

I want to do something like:

```
 context.onended = function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '../scripts/radio.php',
        data: {
          attr1: 'value1'
        },
        success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);

        fileChosen = true;
        setupAudioNodes();

        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

        request.addEventListener("progress", updateProgress);
        request.addEventListener("load", transferComplete);
        request.addEventListener("error", transferFailed);
        request.addEventListener("abort", transferCanceled);

        request.open('GET', data, true);
        request.responseType = 'arraybuffer';

        // When loaded decode the data
        request.onload = function() {

            $("#title").html("Title");
            $("#album").html("Goes");
            $("#artist").html("Here");
            onWindowResize();
            $("#title, #artist, #album").css("visibility", "visible");

            // decode the data
            context.decodeAudioData(request.response, function(buffer) {
            // when the audio is decoded play the sound
            sourceNode.buffer = buffer;
            sourceNode.start(0);

            $("#freq, body").addClass("animateHue");
            //on error
            }, function(e) {
                console.log(e);
            });
        };
        request.send();

    }
    });
```

I want for this to run at the end of a song and play the next file. Which it would work if I could get the end time of the currently playing song.

Answer (score 2):

To fix the above issue I added the .ended event inside the function that the source was set up:

```
function setupAudioNodes() {
    // setup a analyser
    analyser = context.createAnalyser();
    // create a buffer source node
    sourceNode = context.createBufferSource();  
    //connect source to analyser as link
    sourceNode.connect(analyser);
    // and connect source to destination
    sourceNode.connect(context.destination);
    //start updating
    rafID = window.requestAnimationFrame(updateVisualization);
    //I had to place a function for the .ended event inside the function sourceNode was set up.
    sourceNode.onended = function() {
        sourceNode.stop(0);
        playFirst();
}
}
```